# Javascript error in accessing JSON

Tags: javascript

In the following JSON how to access id and name

```
console.log($scope.mylist)

{"data":"{\"projects\":[{\"id\":\"3\",\"title\":\"MYCLOUD\",\"desc\":\"DESC\"}]}"}
```

I tried the following

```
console.log($scope.mylist.data) //undefined
console.log($scope.mylist["data"])//undefined
console.log($scope.mylist.projects)//undefined
console.log($scope.mylist["projects"]) //undefined
```

Comment: note that the json is not valid ....   use this to check http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i have corrected it now

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem (please use the new snippet feature of SO) ?

Comment: The json is still not valid you are missing another bracket in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` property contains JSON, so you need to `JSON.parse` that too.

```
$scope.mylist.data.projects = JSON.parse($scope.mylist.data);
```

Then you should be able to access it with

```
$scope.mylist.data.projects[0].id //etc
```

Though there's an underlying problem of how you're getting/sending that JSON.